# Java adding row of jtable to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, jtable

In Java I would take the data of mysql to jtable. I would just take the data in the some columns. For example, in the database I have 6 columns. I would take 2 columns with the data.

My code :

```
Statement s10 = (Statement) baglanti.createStatement();
try (ResultSet rs10 = s10.executeQuery("Select * from gelirgider.gelir where ay = '" + cbb3s + "' and yil = '" + cbb4s + "'")) { 
    int colcount = rs10.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); 
    DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel();
    for(int i = 1;i<=colcount;i++) {
        tm.addColumn(rs10.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
    } 
    while(rs10.next()) {
        Object[][] sutunge3 = {
            {rs10.getRowId(1).toString() + rs10.getString("etkinlik"), rs10.getString("tutar")},
            {rs10.getRowId(2).toString() + rs10.getString("etkinlik"), rs10.getString("tutar")},
    };
    dtmgelir.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
    dtmgelir.addRow(sutunge3);
    dtmgelir3 = new DefaultTableModel(sutunge3, satir);

    Object[] row = new Object[colcount];
    for(int i=1;i<=colcount;i++) {
        row[i-1] = rs10.getObject(i);
        System.out.println(rs10.getRow());
        tm.addRow(row);
    }
}                               
tgelir.setModel(dtmgelir);
```

Comment: Start with some code and ask more specifically with question related to this code.

Comment: ok. I edit the question

Comment: And what is the problem relating to this code? What does not work as expected?

Comment: This looks like some old-school stuff, and you could probably cut down the technical debt, by using a more modern DAO solution. You are also breaking a cardinal rule, by constructing a query by string concatenation, it is a huge security risk, use ```PreparedStatement```instead.

Comment: The problem is ı don't take the data to column iwant.